# overriding properties

Tags: c#, inheritance

I am inheriting from a class that has this property :

```
public bool isAuthorized
{
    get { return _Authorized; }
    set { _Authorized = value; }
}
```

I am trying to override this in the derived class, but it doesn't recognise `isAuthorized`. Can someone help me with my syntax?

```
public override bool isAuthorized()
{

}
```

This is the error I get :

```
cannot override because 'CDBase.isAuthorized' is not a function
```

EDIT : So if I want the override to always set isAuthorized to true, I would use this syntax?

```
private bool _Authorized = false;

    public override bool isAuthorized 
    {
        get { return _Authorized; }
        set { _Authorized = true; }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set your value always to true you can simply write this code:

```
  public override bool isAuthorized
  {
      get { return true; }
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

its a property, you used as method `isAuthorized()`

`()` - used for methods

you have to do in your derived class

```
public override bool isAuthorized
    {

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Same as when you want your method to be overridable, the property also has to be declared **virtual** in the base class:

```
public virtual bool isAuthorized ...
```

Also you cannot override a propeprty with a method. You can only override the getters and setters in the derived class:

```
public override bool isAuthorized
{
   get { return base.isAuthorized; }
   set { base.isAuthorized = value; } 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The original class should have a virtual, but I suspect you might also have an issue with the fact that you are trying to override a base class property with a derived class method.

If your derived class method looked like this:

```
    public override bool isAuthorized
    {
        get { return _Authorized; }
        set { _Authorized = value; }
    }
```

Then you would need this in your base class:

```
    public virtual bool isAuthorized
    {
        get { return _Authorized; }
        set { _Authorized = value; }
    }
```

Can you maybe desrive more what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: is it a bad practice to use the 'new' keyword like this: 'public new bool IsAuthorized { get; set; }' ?

Comment: @šljaker No. 'New' and 'override' are used for different purposes.

Answer (score 0):

```
public virtual bool isAuthorized
{
    get { return _Authorized; }
    set { _Authorized = value; }
}



public override bool isAuthorized
{
 ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In base class mark the property as `virtual` which you want to be overridden and in derive class use `override` keyword for the property that needs to be overriden.

Comment: Even so, the _overriding_ member is a method, while the base's a property

Answer (score 0):

this

```
   class A
    {
        public virtual string prop { get; set; }
    }

    class B : A
    {
        public override string prop
        {
            get
            {
                return "overridden";
            }
            set
            {
                base.prop = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think you must declare this as Virtual in able to override

Like:

public virtual bool isAuthorized
 {
      get { return _Authorized; }
      set { _Authorized = value; }
 }

Regars,

Answer (score 0):

In base class you can  mark it as virtual, and you can override.
Actually, use reflector we can see the properties are methods, too!

Answer (score 0):

About your error and syntax :
Simply dont use the '()' . You are using property as method.

About how to do it :

There are two ways to implement it in base class. 'new' and 'override'. But their implementations varies regarding to base class.

http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/435f1dw2.aspx

The new modifier instructs the compiler to use your implementation instead of the base class implementation. Any code that is not referencing your class but the base class will use the base class implementation.

```
public bool isAuthorized
 {
     get { return _Authorized; }
     set { _Authorized = value; }
 }


public new bool isAuthorized
 {  //someth    }
```

http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ebca9ah3.aspx

The override modifier may be used on virtual methods and must be used on abstract methods. This indicates for the compiler to use the last defined implementation of a method. Even if the method is called on a reference to the base class it will use the implementation overriding it.

```
public virtual bool isAuthorized
 {
     get { return _Authorized; }
     set { _Authorized = value; }
 }


public override bool isAuthorized
 {  //someth    }
```